# Can this data be pivoted the way I want?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have data that looks as follows:

[image]

I would like to convert this into a single row with the following columns:

```
    SubId,
    Zone1ReadTime,
    Zone1ChamberPressure
    Zone1ChamberTemperature,
    Zone2ReadTime,
    Zone2ChamberPressure
    Zone2ChamberTemperature,
etc...
```

Essentially, for each of the 20 zones for a particular SubId, I want to create a set of 20 columns. I've used the PIVOT function a few times, but don't really know how to handle this.

Comment: if you can adapt this answer to your schema, it should work :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-mssql

Comment: Do you have {Reporting Services|SQL Server Express Edition w. Advanced Services} installed ? This report can be done easily in {Report Builder|SSBIDS}.

Comment: @Hosea146 : Did you find the answer ? If yes, post it here .

Comment: @RaviSingh - No I haven't found the answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/17969)

**Query**

```
create table #demo (SubId int,zone int,ReadTime datetime,ChamberPressure float,ChamberTemp float)

insert into #demo (SubId ,zone ,ReadTime ,ChamberPressure ,ChamberTemp )
values
(1,1,GETDATE(),0.133156,98.4),
(1,2,GETDATE()+1,0.13435,76.4),
(1,3,GETDATE()+2,0.62346,3.4),
(1,4,GETDATE()+3,0.63426,34.4),
(1,5,GETDATE()+4,0.76457,43.4)


select  * from 
    (select  SubId
        --,zone 
        ,case 
            when COL='ReadTime' then 'Zone'+ CAST(zone as varchar) + 'ReadTime'
            when COL='ChamberPressure' then 'Zone'+ CAST(zone as varchar) + 'ChamberPressure'
            when COL='ChamberTemp' then 'Zone'+ CAST(zone as varchar) + 'ChamberTemp'
        end New_Col,    
            Value
        from (select SubId
                    ,zone
                    ,CAST(ReadTime as varchar) ReadTime
                    ,CAST(ChamberPressure as varchar) ChamberPressure
                    ,CAST(ChamberTemp as varchar) ChamberTemp 
                    from #demo
             )a

        UNPIVOT
        (
            Value
            for COL in ([ReadTime],[ChamberPressure],[ChamberTemp])
        )UPVT
    )b
pivot
(
  MAX(Value)
  for New_Col in (Zone1ReadTime,Zone1ChamberPressure,Zone1ChamberTemp
                 ,Zone2ReadTime,Zone2ChamberPressure,Zone2ChamberTemp
                 ,Zone3ReadTime,Zone3ChamberPressure,Zone3ChamberTemp
                 ,Zone4ReadTime,Zone4ChamberPressure,Zone4ChamberTemp
                 ,Zone5ReadTime,Zone5ChamberPressure,Zone5ChamberTemp)
) PVT   


drop table #demo
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/17969/0)**:

```
| SUBID |       ZONE1READTIME | ZONE1CHAMBERPRESSURE | ZONE1CHAMBERTEMP |       ZONE2READTIME | ZONE2CHAMBERPRESSURE | ZONE2CHAMBERTEMP |       ZONE3READTIME | ZONE3CHAMBERPRESSURE | ZONE3CHAMBERTEMP |       ZONE4READTIME | ZONE4CHAMBERPRESSURE | ZONE4CHAMBERTEMP |       ZONE5READTIME | ZONE5CHAMBERPRESSURE | ZONE5CHAMBERTEMP |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     1 | Aug  1 2013  5:50AM |             0.133156 |             98.4 | Aug  2 2013  5:50AM |              0.13435 |             76.4 | Aug  3 2013  5:50AM |              0.62346 |              3.4 | Aug  4 2013  5:50AM |              0.63426 |             34.4 | Aug  5 2013  5:50AM |              0.76457 |             43.4 |
```

You may have to `cast` the result to required `datetype`.